# Dspace OAI - Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, repository, dspace, oai

When we can access to:
http://dspace/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=oai_dc
we have the following error:

```
ene 16, 2018 12:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [oai] en el contexto con ruta [/oai] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] con causa raíz
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.setOutputProperty(TransformerImpl.java:966)
        at com.lyncode.xoai.util.XSLPipeline.apply(XSLPipeline.java:24)
        at com.lyncode.xoai.dataprovider.handlers.ListRecordsHandler.createRecord(ListRecordsHandler.java:159)
        at com.lyncode.xoai.dataprovider.handlers.ListRecordsHandler.handle(ListRecordsHandler.java:124)
        at com.lyncode.xoai.dataprovider.OAIDataProvider.handle(OAIDataProvider.java:213)
        at org.dspace.xoai.controller.DSpaceOAIDataProvider.contextAction(DSpaceOAIDataProvider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We try import and clear cache of oai using:

## ./dspace oai import -c

## ./dsapce oai clear-cache

but the error persist
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2568 this may be linked to character encodings. When you run the oai commands on the command line, are you using UTF8 character encoding? And is your DSpace set up correctly for UTF8? Eg see the set-up instructions in the [official DSpace installation instructions](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-ServletEngine(ApacheTomcat7orlater,Jetty,CauchoResinorequivalent)).